# WHOIS data accuracy policy: can the domain be cancelled?

Tags: domains, whois

I am trying to contact the owner of a domain name regarding potential purchase of the name. The owner's listed contact doesn't work, I never got any replies from him/her. (In fact, the contacts are protected by DomainsByProxy.com, tried to contact them too, no luck in helping me with finding the owner.)

So, does ICANN's Whois Data Accuracy policy mean the domain can be cancelled on the grounds of owners not being reachable via WHOIS data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does appear so:
https://support.logicboxes.com/kb/servlet/KBServlet/faq658.html
http://www.icann.org/en/announcements/advisory-10may02.htm

However just because someone doesn't reply doesn't mean that the contact information is wrong.

Comment: Looks like "invalid" means just that, inability to reach a person. Found this: http://www.networknewz.com/2011/01/03/large-domains-suspended-to-invalid-whois-data/ so both NetSol and GoDaddy can suspend a domain if the owner doesn't respond to emails.

Comment: There's a difference between them not responding to you, and them not responding to the registrar.

Comment: true, but I can file a complaint. Honestly, I don't want to upset the owner who either simply ignores my requests or doesn't read emails at the listed address at all. But the domain is not developed (the web site is empty), OTOH I'm in the process of registering a trademark, so what is the easiest way to obtain the domain with "minimum bloodshed"?

Comment: Well, you can file a complaint. But honestly, this is going to be cumbersome and quite frankly, not as easy as it may sound.

Comment: Also found this: https://supportcenter.godaddy.com/DomainServices/ReportInvalidWhois.aspx?DomainName=example.com it says: *The registrant is not required to respond to an email, phone, or postal mail inquiry. We need evidence that the email is invalid (such as a bounce), the phone is invalid (such as a disconnection), or the email has been returned as undeliverable.*